How to perform healthcheck of Kafka connection using kotlin-kafka?
There is a kotlin-kafka in use in the current codebase, so the raw Kafka-client does not seem to be exposed and developer interacts with a io.github.nomisRev.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver wrapper.
What would be the right way to understand that Kafka consumer related to given KafkaReceiver is still working as expected (the connection to Kafka is alive and polling is working).
I see that cohort project is using a last-poll-seconds-ago metric. Is there any way to get such information from kotlin-kafka API?

Created a feature request in kotlin-kafka project
